# Strange results for the Gem.latest_version_for(name) method

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am working on a gem related utility and I have observed strange results using Gem.latest_version_for method. Here are some observations under irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> Gem.latest_version_for('rails').to_s
=> "5.2.2"
irb(main):002:0> Gem.latest_version_for('gosu').to_s
=> "0.7.38"
```

Note how the first line, gets the correct version of rails, 5.2.2 as I write this and checking with rubygems.org confirms this. The query for the gosu gem returns 0.7.38 which is wildly wrong. The correct answer should be 0.14.4

I am at a loss to explain what is happening here.

I can confirm that my host is https://rubygems.org and

```
C:\Sites\mysh
8 mysh>ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
C:\Sites\mysh
9 mysh>gem --version
2.5.2
```

Comment: how about `gem update --system` because your version is a bit old ruby gems is up to `2.7.8` now and under both `2.7.7` and `2.7.6` I get `0.14.4` for `gosu`. On both a linux and a windows machine using 2.2.3, 1.9.3, and 2.5.0 ruby versions

Comment: That was my first thought. The relevant code is unchanged. I could give it a try anyway. There should be no harm in running the current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version available for `i386-mingw32` platform is 0.7.38. You'll note this comports with what your ruby version is reported as.

https://rubygems.org/gems/gosu/versions

`latest_version_for` calls `latest_spec_for`, which calls `Gem::SpecFetcher.spec_for_dependency` with only the name of the gem as an argument. `spec_for_dependency` takes another argument, `matching_platform`, which defaults to true.

It looks like `latest_version_for` is scoped to your current platform thru that chain, with the `matching_platform` default. The `gem install` command might treat i386/x386 as the same/equivalent and allow them.

[spec_for_dependency](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubygems/rubygems/Gem%2FSpecFetcher%3Aspec_for_dependency)

```
if matching_platform is false, gems for all platforms are returned
```

You should be able to mirror the `latest_spec_for` method and pass in the `multi_platform` argument to override. Something like

```
dependency     = Gem::Dependency.new name
fetcher        = Gem::SpecFetcher.fetcher
spec_tuples, _ = fetcher.spec_for_dependency dependency, true # true added here
```

Comment: I see that, Odd thing is that Gem.platforms returns "ruby" and "x86-mingw32". This should have matched the 0.14.4 - October 09, 2018 x86-mingw32 version. Further, gem install gosu gets the x86-mingw32 version. So something else must be going on here.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri I added some additional info about the lookup path and noted the method that looks like it's scoping on platform.

Comment: Looking at spec_for_dependency(dependency, matching_platform=true) we see the default is already true. Adding false returns all possible platforms, adding true returns the same three specs. I extracted the version and platform from these and got [["0.7.38", "x86-mingw32"], ["0.14.4", "ruby"], ["0.14.4", "x86-mingw32"]]. Note how x86-mingw32 occurs twice in the list, once for 0.7.38 and again for 0.14.4. Note that latest_spec_for answers the first enry in the list. The wrong one.

Comment: I meant to say "is indeed true", but 5 minutes had already gone by.

Answer (score 0):

With the excellent help of Jay Dorsey, I think I have made some progress here. What I need to say is too large to fit in a comment and is the actual answer to the question about the odd behavior. Well at least I am pretty sure that it is.

As mentioned above: latest_version_for calls latest_spec_for, which calls Gem::SpecFetcher.spec_for_dependency.

The key is that that method then calls Gem::SpecFetcher.search_for_dependency. This is a long rambling method. I want to focus of one line that occurs after the specs have be obtained:

```
tuples = tuples.sort_by { |x| x[0] }
```

This sorts the tuples which are an array of [spec, source] arrays. It sorts them in ascending version/platform (as far as I can tell)

Now we return to the Gem class method latest_spec_for(name) and in particular the line:

```
spec, = spec_tuples.first
```

This grabs the first sub-array and keeps the spec and discards the source.

Note that it grabs the first element. The one with the lowest version number. This is normally not a problem because for the vast majority of gems, there will be only one spec present. Not so for the gosu gem. Here there are three due to the fact that gosu contains platform specific code. It seems to grab specs for the two Gem platforms ("ruby" and "x86-mingw32") and also the ruby platform (i386-mingw32).

To test my idea, I created the file glmp.rb (get last monkey patch) Here it is:

```
# The latest_spec_for(name) monkey patch.

module Gem

  # Originally in  File rubygems.rb at line 816
  def self.latest_spec_for(name)
    dependency   = Gem::Dependency.new name
    fetcher      = Gem::SpecFetcher.fetcher
    spec_tuples, = fetcher.spec_for_dependency dependency

    spec_tuples[-1][0]
  end

end
```

Now I know monkey patching is frowned upon, but for now this is just to test the idea. Here are my results:

```
36 mysh>=Gem.latest_version_for('gosu')
Gem::Version.new("0.7.38")
C:\Sites\ideas\gem_usage
37 mysh>ls
gem_latest.rb  gem_usage.rb  glmp.rb
C:\Sites\ideas\gem_usage
39 mysh>=require './glmp'
true
C:\Sites\ideas\gem_usage
40 mysh>=Gem.latest_version_for('gosu')
Gem::Version.new("0.14.4")
```

While I can use this hack to solve my problem for now, I think I will raise an issue with rubygems bringing up this matter.